Is there a way to make my wordpress mobile navigation open on top of a sticky group below it?
I am fairly new to webdesign and still learning coding but I have built my wordpress site and now I am trying to optimize it for mobile. At present the first problem I am encountering is that when the collapsed menu on mobile is opened it sits behind the other elements that are intended to be the body of the home page. I intended for the body elements to scroll up and cover the header, then each other at varying breakpoints and that functions as intended and I don't want to change that. Is there a way to make my navigation menu open on top of those while keeping that functionality how it is?
website - www.jelbdesign.com
before opening the menu it functions as intended after you will see the menu hides behind the body.
Picture for reference:
(https://i.sstatic.net/TDkiHsJj.png)
I have attempted to adjust the z-index but I am not overly familiar with it so I don't know if I am doing it wrong or if that is just not what would provide the solution I am looking for. See css for z-index:
.body-primary--home {
position: sticky;
z-index: 1;
border: none;
height: fit;
margin-bottom: fit;
margin-top: fit;
}

navigation.nav-primary--mobile {
position: relative;
z-index: 2 !important;
height: fit;
margin-bottom: fit;
margin-top: fit;
}

I have tried adjusting the values for position, height, and the z-index numbers themselves to different values and it isn't working, nothings changing visibly no matter what I adjust.
I have primarily used the WordPress block editor up until this point and with my limited knowledge I am just stuck and not sure where else to look for the solution.

The method I use for isolating these kind of problems is to use my browser to save a local copy of the rendered page. I then edit that local copy in a text editor to simplify the code, removing everything which is not relevant to the problem, until the structure becomes simple enough that the problem becomes clear.

Just a question on the design of your site ... how is it supposed to work on desktop? Currently as you scroll down, the Jamie Bruce section is in front of your nav menu ... is that how you want it to work, or should the menu stay at the front?

That was the intent yes, there are links through out the design for navigation the issue is keeping that same flow on mobile but having the collapsible navigation open over it when tapped/clicked on. Everything I tried above didn't resolve that and I'm so new to coding that I'm not entirely sure what to look for. Unfortunately when I was in college they seemed to place web design and coding as one of the least important subjects so I'm learning on my own now in between a lot of other responsibilities and it is slow progress.

If I can't figure it out here I may try reaching out to some former classmates/professors to see if they may have some advice to offer or at least point me in the right direction to look up the solution myself. While getting my associates they wanted to focus on Dreamweaver a now defunct platform and getting my bachelors they taught the bare bones basics and didn't even get past HTML into CSS.

All the .wp-container-xy elements in your #Home-Page-Header have z-index: 10; set. But since you want the first element to come in front of the others, you'll need to give that one a higher z-index.
